# Inserting a list into a listbox in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, list, listbox

I have made a list and the data is added into the list by the user using textboxes and comboboxes, I am now trying to enter this list of data into a listbox but everytime I try to add the data I get the output as the class name e.g WindowApplicaion.Journey or it comes out as System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WindowApplication.Journey], i'm not sure if this is due to me placing the conversion code in the wrong place or i'm just doing it all wrong, here is my code for both cases:

```
private void ShowAllToursbttn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Tour t in company.tours)
        {   
            string converter = company.tours.ToString();
            ToursListBox.Items.Add(converter);
        } 
    }
```

or

```
private void ShowAllToursbttn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Tour t in company.tours)
        {

            string ConvertedList = string.Join(" ", company.tours);
            TourListBox.Items.Add(ConvertedList);
        }
    }
```

Where tours is my list I created in my company class and t is each instance in the list, any advice would be great, thank you!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WindowApplication
{
    class Tour 
    {
    private string custFirstname;
    private string custSurname;
    private string custAddress;
    private string pickupArea;
    private string pickupDateandTime;
    private string pickupDescription;
    private string destinationArea;
    private string destinationDescription;


    //Creating getters and setters for each attribute
    #region getters/setters
    public string firstname
    {
        get { return custFirstname; }
        set { custFirstname = value; }
    }

    public string surname
    {
        get { return custSurname; }
        set { custSurname = value; }
    }

    public string address
    {
        get { return custAddress; }
        set { custAddress = value; }
    }

    public string pickuparea
    {
        get { return pickupArea; }
        set { pickupArea = value; }
    }

    public string pickupdateandtime
    {
        get { return pickupDateandTime; }
        set { pickupDateandTime = value; }
    }

    public string pickupescription
    {
        get { return pickupDescription; }
        set { pickupDescription = value; }
    }

    public string destinationarea
    {
        get { return destinationArea; }
        set { destinationArea = value; }
    }

    public string destinationdescription
    {
        get { return destinationDescription; }
        set { destinationDescription = value; }
    }

}
```

}

That is my Tour class.

```
private void AddThisTourbttn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        Tour t = new Tour();
        t.firstname = CustomerFirstnameTxt.Text;
        t.surname = CustomerSurnameTxt1.Text;
        t.address = CustomerAddressTxt.Text;
        t.pickupdateandtime = TourDateTimeTxt.Text;
        t.pickuparea = TourPickupArea.Text;
        t.pickupescription = TourPickupDescriptionTxt.Text;
        t.destinationarea = TourDestinationArea.Text;
        t.destinationdescription = TourDestinationDescriptionTxt.Text;
        company.addTour(t);

    }
```

and on my MainWindow I have assigned each textbox to its appropriate get/set.

Comment: Can we see the Tour class definition? You are assigning the whole object to the list.

Comment: Yeah sorry, just edited the post.

Comment: One more thing... what is the value that you want to be displayed in the ListBox? desitnationarea?

Comment: I am trying to display all of the data in the list for each instance, so firstname,surname,address,pickuparea etc

Comment: Ah ok... so your're logic is a little off. Is there a collection of Tours? That would be the only reason you would need that foreach. Otherwise you could just add each property of the Tour object to the ListBox.

Comment: In the end there will be more than 1 tours, how do you think I should go about this? @MikeSchwartz

Comment: I don't think stacking the collection of tours into one listbox would  be very pretty. You might need to think of a different way to display multiple tours.

Comment: I can change what i'm outputting my list to at a later stage, I just want to know why instead of outputting the data held within the list, it outputs the class name and how I can fix that? @MikeSchwartz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program displaying class name in listbox because you use default object's toString() method in ShowAllToursbttn_Click, which will output class name. Try to override ToString() method in Tour class, to output string with your desired format for example:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return String.Format("Firstname: {0}; Surname: {1}", firstname, surname);
}
```

And change ShowAllToursbttn_Click logic to:

```
private void ShowAllToursbttn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Tour t in company.tours)
    {
        TourListBox.Items.Add(t.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the  help, my friend helped me figure out the problem, it was an issue with my return method in my class (: